# Dusk user auth session is shared across test methods in a Test Class in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

So I have multiple methods in a single Test Class.

In the first method the factory user is created goes to login fills login credentials and assertPathis('/home'). This method runs without any problem.

```
public function test_user_should_see_home()
    {

        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'name' => 'first',
            'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',

        ]);


        $this->browse(function ($browser) use($user){
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'secret')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/home');
        });

    }
```

In the second method again factory user is created goes to login and fills credentials and makes some assertion.

```
public function test_user_should_see_login()
    {

        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'name' => 'second',
            'email' => 'abcd@gmail.com',
        ]);

        $this->browse(function ($browser) use($user){
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/login');
        });
    }
```

But the second method fails with the error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='email']"}
```

And I looked at the screenshot error it shows the user is at home page and since the logged in user cannot go to login, the test fails.

So how can I make dusk to treat every method as a separate test rather then sharing session across methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to delete the cookies between tests:

```php
protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    foreach(static::$browsers as $browser) {
        $browser->driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?